# Android emulator 30.8.4 not work on Apple M1

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, apple-m1

### System details

> Blockquote
> Mac OS 11.6 (Big Sur)
>
> Device - Mac book pro with M1 chip
>
> Android Studio version - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2

### Error Stack

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.8.4.0 (build_id 7600983) (CL:N/A)
<br>
emulator: INFO: ignore sdcard for arm at api level >= 30
<br>
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
<br>
cannot add library /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
<br>
cannot add library /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
<br>
EglOsGlLibrary: Could not open GL library libGLESv2.dylib [dlopen(libGLESv2.dylib, 2): no suitable image found.
<br>
Did find:
    /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libGLESv2.dylib: code signature in 
<br>(/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libGLESv2.dylib) not]
EglOsEglDispatcher: Could not open EGL library libEGL.dylib [dlopen(libEGL.dylib, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libEGL.dylib: code signature in (/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libEGL.dylib) not valid fo]
```

Android emulator version - 30.0.26 was running perfectly as expected. But after 30.8.4.0 update its not working.

Comment: Can you put the error as code? it increases readability of the question

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: You need to change the java version to 1.8 and the rebuild the android project. It's worked for me. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem with Android emulator 31.2.9, what helped me was switching to **Google Play System image** instead of pure **arm64-v8a** image